# Oracle error: Application failover does not support non-single-SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

We are getting the following error using Oracle:

[Oracle JDBC Driver]Application failover does not support non-single-SELECT statement

The error occurs when we try to make a delete or insert over a large number of rows (tens of millions of rows).

I know that the script works, because it was working for almost an year before these error messages start to pop.

We know that no one change any database configuration, so we figure out that the problem must be on the volume of processed data (row number is growing as time goes by...).

But we never see that kind of error before! What does it means? It seems that a failover engine tries to recover from an error, but when oracle is 'taken over' by this engine, it enter in a more restricted state, where some kinds of queries does not work (like Windows Safe Mode...)

Well, if this is what is happening, how can I get the real error message? The one that trigger the failover mechanism?

BTW, below is one of the deletes that triggers the error:

delete from odf_ca_rnv_av_snapshot_week

(we tried this one just to test the simplest delete we could think of... a truncate won't help us with the real deal :) )

Comment: Is there any chance there are triggers or something like that which would go off when you perform the delete?

Comment: I'll check for triggers... we did not add any triggers, but we are working inside a bigger framework that creates some audit triggers automatically. We did not request audit on the tables we are working, but I need to check to confirm if empty triggers were not created.

Comment: Also consider foreign keys and cascade delete

Answer (score 0):

check [this link](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000029534)

the error seems to come not from Oracle or JDBC, but from "progress". It means that it can only recover from `SELECT` statements and not from DML.

You'll have to figure out why the failover occurs in the first place.

Comment: I forgot that I'd asked this qustion! Sorry!

Comment: I forgot that I'd asked this qustion! Sorry! The week was pretty intense... after some time we discovered that the delete had blow some internal memory of the oracle server. From that point on, some features of the database stopped working. The DBAs asked (orderered...) that we break the delete operation in more than one delete, each one deleting smaller chunks of the table (truncate wasn't an option because the real delete had a where clause...).